# OpenLayers rules and context, what is the difference?

Tags: openlayers-2, style, differences

OpenLayers.Style employs two properties, "rule" and "context" which accordingly contain an array of OpenLayers.Rule and a set of methods.

I have noticed that "context" can somehow substitute "rule". For example, in a case where there is a vector layer displaying temperatures as features, with "temp" in its properties for the values.

```
var temperatureStyle1 = new OpenLayers.Style({
    //common symbolizer styles
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    label: "${temp}", 
    fontColor: "${coltem}",
    fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    {
    context: {
        coltem: function(feature) { 
            var temperature=parseInt(feature.attributes.temp);
            var col="#000000";
            if(temperature>35) { col="#CF2900"; } //Hot
            if(temperature<0) { col="#0000FF"; } //Cold
            return col; 
        }
    }
});
```

is somehow equivalent to

```
    var temperatureStyle2 = new OpenLayers.Style({
        //common symbolizer styles
        fontFamily: "Arial",
        label: "${temp}", 
        //fontColor: "${coltem}", not really needed
        fontWeight: "bold"
        },
        {
        rules: [
            new OpenLayers.Rule({
                filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LESS_THAN,
                    property: "temp",
                    value: 0
                    }),
                symbolizer: { fontColor: "#0000FF" }
                }),
            new OpenLayers.Rule({
                filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.GREATER_THAN,
                    property: "temp",
                    value: 35
                    }),
                symbolizer: { fontColor: "#CF2900" }
                }),
            new OpenLayers.Rule({
                elseFilter: true,
                symbolizer: { fontColor: "#000000" }
                })
            ]
        });
```

What are the benefits in each of these two approaches? I can only see that with "context" I can change only one style (of the symbolizer) at a time, while with "rules" I can redefine a whole symbolizer -- instead of making many context methods for each style doing the same comparison every time.

Is there anything more that I cannot see? What's the reason for the existence of the "context" object?

Answer (score 2):

When you work strictly with rules, your styles can be serialised to SLD, otherwise not. Working with static styles and context has a slight performance benefit.